# Cannot listen to the state change in flutter riverpod

Tags: flutter, state, riverpod

When I change the dropdown value in one file (dropdown.dart), I want to access the change value in other file total.dart.

Dropdown.dart

```
Expanded dropDown(WidgetRef ref, String id) {
  var items = ref.watch(TripProvider.listItemProvider);
  return Expanded(
    child: DropdownButtonFormField(
      hint: const Text('Select items'),
      items: items.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((Map<String, dynamic> res) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: res['id'],
          child: Text(res['item']),
        );
      }).toList(),
      onChanged: (val) {
        TripProvider.onDropDownChange(
          val!,
          ref,
          id,
        );
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

Total.dart

```
class TotalData extends StatelessWidget {
  const TotalData({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer(builder: (_, ref, __) {
      var arrayItem = ref.watch(TripProvider.listProvider);
      print("arrayItem: $arrayItem");
      return Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: const <Text>[
          Text('Unit price: Rs. 500'),
          Text('Total: Rs.1950'),
        ],
      );
    });
  }
}
```

And provider file

```
 static var onDropDownChange =
      (String value, WidgetRef ref, String itemArrayId) {
    var oldState = ref.read(TripProvider.listProvider);
    var items = ref.read(TripProvider.listItemProvider);
    for (var i = 0; i < oldState.length; i++) {
      if (oldState[i]['id'] == itemArrayId) {
        oldState[i]['selectedItem'] = value;
      }
      for (var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
        if (items[j]['id'] == oldState[i]['selectedItem']) {
          oldState[i]['unitPrice'] = items[j]['price'];
        }
      }
    }
    ref.read(TripProvider.listProvider.notifier).update((state) => oldState);
  };
```

[image: When i change dropdown button I want to change the unit price value]

I want to access the state change in total.dart. Is there anything I am missing? I am unable to listen to changes that happen in provider file in total.dart file.

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't provided your whole `TripProvider`, let me show you a simple way to use riverpod to listen to the state change.

```
// create a provider that stores string value (like your dropdown value)
final selectedTripProvider = StateProvider<String>((ref) => "");
```

Dropdown.dart

```
Expanded dropDown(WidgetRef ref, String id) {
  var items = ref.watch(TripProvider.listItemProvider);
  return Expanded(
    child: DropdownButtonFormField(
      hint: const Text('Select items'),
      items: items.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((Map<String, dynamic> res) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: res['id'],
          child: Text(res['item']),
        );
      }).toList(),
      onChanged: (val) {
        // look here
        ref.read(selectedTripProvider.notifier).state = val ?? "";
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

Total.dart

```
class TotalData extends StatelessWidget {
  const TotalData({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer(builder: (_, ref, __) {
      // look Here
      final selectedTrip= ref.watch(selectedTripProvider);
      print("selectedTrip: $selectedTrip");
      return Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: const <Text>[
          Text('Unit price: Rs. 500'),
          Text('Total: Rs.1950'),
        ],
      );
    });
  }
}
```